# Output of ADC when no input is supplied

Tags: adc, power-electronics, raspberry-pi, embedded, thermistor

I am working with a Raspberry Pi 3b+ connected to an [MCP3008](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTwgr.png) ADC to read sensor output.

When the sensor is not connected it gives some floating value (max. value). Is it possible to get a value of zero when no sensor is connected?

My connection is as shown:

[image]

Comment: Pull down resistor should do the trick. Ensure it's high enough so it doesn't interfere with the NTC circuit. A buffer amp would be a good idea I think.

Comment: Can you clarify where the "disconnection" occurs?  Is it between the TEMP1_IN markings, or is the thermistor itself on a lead and can disconnect? 

If the latter, put a resistor of say 100K in parallel with TH1 on the ADC side of the cable (so it can't be disconnected), then rescale.  This will give a well defined, but  none zero disconnected value.

Comment: @colintd the disconnection is the thermister itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the disconnection is the sensor itself (either lead) there is no simple way to get 0V in, however you can (perhaps) detect the unreasonably high voltage, interpret it as a failed sensor, and do something like that in software.

This is a common problem in heating controls with NTC thermistor sensors since a disconnected sensor looks rather similar to a sensor that is extremely cold, so the heat stays on, which can be undesirable.

You will probably need a better clamp circuit than a 3.3V zener which will not allow the voltage to get anywhere near the 5V reference voltage.

If you have no access to the software, it would be possible to make a comparator and analog switch do something similar, but obviously that's more parts and trouble for something that might be a line or two of code. The same comments apply regarding the clamp in this case as well.

Comment: i have edited the schematic from 5tv to 3.3 v. kindly check

Comment: The zener may still affect the voltage too much to reliably detect the broken sensor. Low voltage zeners have very soft "knees" (they conduct significantly well before you reach the rated voltage). This is for you to calculate based on the exact zener characteristics, your thermistor characteristics and the limits of the operating temperature.

Comment: It also shows some random value after disconnection of the sensor and not always max value.